# Python subprocess won't talk to me

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script which runs another python script as a subprocess. The original script communicates with the subprocess using stdin and stdout. I cannot get the subprocess to reply to messages from the original process.

As a minimal example, say I have a script asker.py that wants to get an answer from answerer.py. Asker sends a message to stdin of answerer, and answerer has to send a message back, which asker will print.

asker.py looks like this:

```
import sys
import subprocess as sub

answerer = sub.Popen(["python", "answerer.py"], stdin=sub.PIPE, stdout=sub.PIPE)
answerer.stdin.write("Are you listening?\n")
answerer.stdin.flush()
reply = answerer.stdout.readline()
print reply
```

answerer.py looks like this:

```
while (True):
   line = raw_input()
   print "Yes!"
```

I'm not seeing anything get printed by asker.py. Instead, it just hangs on the `readline()` call. If I run answerer.py directly from the command line, it replies to input that I type in just fine, so how do I get it to reply to asker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subprocess isn't actually writing anything to its own stdout, so nothing is reaching the parent.

The [documentation for sys.stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) notes

> When interactive, stdout and stderr streams are line-buffered. Otherwise, they are block-buffered like regular text files.

That means that when you `print "Yes!"`, it goes into an in-memory buffer, and sits there until it's explicitly flushed, some amount of output data is produced (I think 4 KB is typical), or the program exits normally.

The best fix would be to update your subprocess script to something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
while True:
  line = input()
  sys.stdout.write("Yes!\n")
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 2):

Flush `stdout` not `stdin`:

```
answerer.stdout.flush()  # line 6
```

Or test without `while True:` so the answerer.py gets terminated and `Yes!` gets flushed automatically.

Tested on

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Apr  4 2017, 08:47:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)] on darwin
```